# My sql sorting varchar field with numeric part

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table data_table .I need to get all the title from the table.The title field (type varchar) contain alphanumeric data like below

```
title
---------
ab 2007
ab 2017
ba 2018
ba 2017
cd 2017
cd 2016
```

My desired output is

```
 title
---------
 ba 2018
 ab 2017
 ba 2017
 cd 2017
 cd 2016
 ab 2007
```

I tried by CAST .But didnt get required result

```
SELECT title, CAST(title as SIGNED) AS casted_column FROM data_table ORDER BY `title` DESC
```

Comment: Secretly, I think you know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RIGHT` to get last 4 digits and then cast it to unsigned and sort it

```
SELECT title 
from tbl
order by cast(right(title,4) as unsigned) desc, title desc
```

Answer (score 1):

if your title end always with  4 digit  you could  substr for obtain the number and use in sort

```
      SELECT title
      FROM data_table
      ORDER BY substr(`title`, -4) DESC , title DESC
```